# How do I completely remove a node from memory from a linked list using python?

Tags: python-3.x, memory, linked-list

```
def delete(self,data):
    if self.head.data ==data:
        temp = self.head
        self.head=self.head.next
        del temp
    else :
        node= self.head
        while node.next:
            if node.next.data==data:
                temp=node.next
                node.next=node.next.next
                del temp
```

How to delete node from linked list implemented using python? Can "del temp" delete node from memory?

Comment: No, `del` does not delete an object from memory, it deletes a name from a namespace. Python provides *no mechanisms for manually managing memory* Python is a memory managed language, the CPython implementation uses reference counting. When a reference count reaches zero, an object is immediately reclaimed

Comment: Thank you:) Then, will this node be automatically deleted without directly deleting it?

Comment: Only if it's reference count is zero (or if it part of an unreachable reference cycle). But yes, probably. This is how you would do things.